# surface of white région on black image (mask)

Tags: python, opencv, k-means, image-segmentation

I have a problem, I don't know how to calculate the surface of each white region in a black mask, I am looking for a programme which provides me with a list of the surface of each white building

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you simply want the area of each white region (i.e. the count of white pixels in each white region).  Once you have your black/white image, find the contours. Then get the contour area. See cv2.findContours() and cv2.contourArea() in the OpenCV documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),

Comment: thanks a lot..that what I was looking for